# Why when i edit a MultiPolygon type geometry in the map it changes to Polygon type?

Tags: javascript, django, google-maps, polygon, geojson

Im working with GeoDjango and drawing with google maps api 3.
When i turn editable:True and edit a MultiPolygon type geometry, it changes to a Polygon type in the GeoJson properties, but i need to work all my geometries in MultiPolygon.

I search in the web, but all what i found was "how to change MultiPolygon to Polygon", but i dont want that.

This is my model in django

```
class Potrero(models.Model):
    sector = models.ForeignKey(Sector,editable=False)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    superficie = models.FloatField(editable=False)
    vector = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326,default=None)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
class Meta:
    unique_together = (("nombre","sector"),)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.nombre
```

I transform the geodjango data in json with geojson method and transfer it with the HttpResponse in the variable "lhope".

My code in javascript:

This is how is drawing the features:

```
    map.data.addGeoJson(lhope);
    map.data.setStyle(function (feature) {
        var fcolor = feature.getProperty('fillColor');
        var scolor = feature.getProperty('strokeColor');
        var sopacity = feature.getProperty('strokeOpacity');
        var edit = feature.getProperty('editable');
        return {
            fillColor: fcolor,
            strokeColor: scolor,
            strokeOpacity: sopacity,
            editable:edit,
            strokeWeight: 2.0
            };
    });
```

when i begin to edit:

```
var f = map.data.getFeatureById(feature_id);
      f.setProperty('editable',true);
```

And when i finish the edition:

```
var f = map.data.getFeatureById(feature_id);
      f.setProperty('editable',false);
var new_potrero;
      f.toGeoJson(function(new_potrero){
            alert(JSON.stringify( new_potrero,null,4));
            $.get( {dataType:"json",url:"{% url 'geoinfo:get_edit_potrero' %}", data:{ idi: f.getId(), poly: JSON.stringify( new_potrero,null,4) }}) ;
        });
```

when i turn "editable":true and dont change any vertice of the geometry this is what i get from the alert(JSON.stringify):

> {
>       "type": "Feature",
>       "geometry": {
>           "type": "MultiPolygon",
>           "coordinates": [
>               [
>                   [
>                       [
>                           -70.57841420173798,
>                           -32.759643227220906
>                       ],
>                       [
>                           -70.57747006416474,
>                           -32.76220103881522
>                       ],
>                       [
>                           -70.57895064354096,
>                           -32.76180406405501
>                       ],
>                       [
>                           -70.57904791831032,
>                           -32.761693993357056
>                       ],
>                       [
>                           -70.57907938957368,
>                           -32.76165519806363
>                       ],
>                       [
>                           -70.58059215545808,
>                           -32.760225169648976
>                       ],
>                       [
>                           -70.57841420173798,
>                           -32.759643227220906
>                       ]
>                   ]
>               ]
>           ]
>       },
>       "properties": {
>           "fillColor": "#FFFF00",
>           "strokeColor": "#FFFF00",
>           "strokeOpacity": 0.8,
>           "editable": false
>       },
>       "id": 143
>   }

And its correct because the type still be "MultiPolygon"

But, when i change any vertice of the geometry, this is what i get:

> {
>       "type": "Feature",
>       "geometry": {
>           "type": "Polygon",
>           "coordinates": [
>               [
>                   [
>                       -70.57841420173798,
>                       -32.759643227220906
>                   ],
>                   [
>                       -70.57483077049409,
>                       -32.76059734013807
>                   ],
>                   [
>                       -70.57747006416474,
>                       -32.76220103881522
>                   ],
>                   [
>                       -70.57895064354096,
>                       -32.76180406405501
>                   ],
>                   [
>                       -70.57904791831032,
>                       -32.761693993357056
>                   ],
>                   [
>                       -70.57907938957368,
>                       -32.76165519806363
>                   ],
>                   [
>                       -70.58262526989137,
>                       -32.7619145856149
>                   ],
>                   [
>                       -70.58059215545808,
>                       -32.760225169648976
>                   ],
>                   [
>                       -70.57841420173798,
>                       -32.759643227220906
>                   ]
>               ]
>           ]
>       },
>       "properties": {
>           "fillColor": "#00FF00",
>           "strokeColor": "#FFFF00",
>           "strokeOpacity": 0.8,
>           "editable": false
>       },
>       "id": 143
>   }

If you can see the type now is Polygon and its the same Feature.

All the code is working fine, no errors founded except the one what im asking.

Also is important to say that this error only appears in the features with only 1 polygon in the set, if i edit any feature that have more than 1 polygone in the set it maintains the "type":"MultiPolygon".

I'm really worried about this, because i need to work all my features as MultiPoligon.
Thanks for any support that u can give me.

Comment: well you need not be, a multipolygon with one polygon inside it is well, a polygon!!

Comment: Yes, but i'm working with MultiPolygons, if the system change the type of my collections i will have some errors because my code is oriented to work with MultiPolygons not Polygons and if you see they have some diference like:
Polygons: [[[ "Polygon" ]]] ; while 
MultiPolygons: [[[[ "Polygon" ]]]]

Comment: I don't see how that becomes an issue